# Error initializating a generic version of Java singleton on the fly (single line)

Tags: java, android, generics, singleton, strong-parameters

**Scenario:** Exactly I am translating a my own `Objective-C` library to enable the same functionality to `Android` development using `Java` which is, a `Singleton` contains a `Hashtable<String, V>` `(NSMutableDictionary in Objective-C)` to facilitate programmer to `inject` and `pop` values based on `key-value coding`. The code is as follows...

**Singleton.java**

```
import java.util.Hashtable;

public class Singleton<V> {

    private static volatile Singleton sharedInstance = null;

    private Hashtable<String, V> sharedHashtable;

    private Singleton() {

        sharedHashtable = new Hashtable<String, V>();
    }

    public static Singleton getSharedInstance() {

        if (sharedInstance == null) {

            sharedInstance = new Singleton();
        }

        return sharedInstance;
    }

    public void inject(String key, V value) {

        sharedHashtable.put(key, value);
    }

    public V popValue(String key) {

        return sharedHashtable.get(key);
    }
}
```

**Main.java**

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        // Part 1

        Singleton<String> stringVersion = Singleton.getSharedInstance();

        stringVersion.inject("RAMStringKey", "Hello I am Using SO");

        String string = stringVersion.popValue("RAMStringKey");

        // Part 2

        Singleton<Integer> integerVersion = Singleton.getSharedInstance();

        integerVersion.inject("RAMIntegerKey", 5);

        Integer integer = integerVersion.popValue("RAMIntegerKey");

        System.out.println(string);
        System.out.println(integer);

        // Part 3

        String anotherString = Singleton.getSharedInstance().popValue("RAMStringKey"); // Error:(27, 70) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String

    }
}
```

**Problem:** I have succeeded to achieve strong typing therefore I can inject any object (String or Integer) and pop any object. But in the Part 3 I am trying to do the same on the fly (in single line) but it is giving an error

```
Error:(27, 70) java: incompatible types: java.lang.Object cannot be converted to java.lang.String
```

I am really trying to do something like:

```
String anotherString = Singleton<String>.getSharedInstance().popValue("RAMKey");
```

but it is not allowed.

**How can I create a singleton in a single line exactly like in part 3?** 
Can anyone help me to achieve that? 
Where should I make the change?

**Tip:** Part 3 is the single line version of Part 1

Answer (score 0):

The type parameter is used at compile time for type checking. The `Singleton` class does not know about the type parameter, instances may know about type parameters. The first call to `Singleton.getSharedInstance()` creates a `HashMap<String,Object>` in part 1. Its legal to store `String` or `Integer` values in this map.
In part 3 `getSharedInstance()` accesses a map `HashMap<String,Object>`, thus `popValue()` returns an `Object` which cannot be cast to a `String` as the error says.

Please note there is only one static instance `sharedInstance`, not one per used type parameter!

And since you mentioned Android: Be careful with singletons in android: If the application is exited and restarted it is not guaranteed that the VM has been restarted for your application. This means a singleton instance from a previous run might survive and its state might or might not be useful for the new run.

Comment: Thanks and I have edited the question to avoid some language ambiguity. The question is: How to achieve the same functionality which is mentioned in Part 1 and 2 in Part 3 single line rather creating and assigning a object like `Singleton<Integer> integerVersion`

Comment: Please read the question again I made a big change. I hope that you can understand my problem easily.

Comment: Unless you provide your singleton with multiple map for the different value types there is no way, because there is only one instance of your Singleton not one instance per type variable instance. The problem is not getting the single line version running. The problem is that the singleton is a class and not a template.

Comment: Thank you, let me consider it.